# How to attach screenshots to Allure report from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, jenkins, xctest, allure

How to attach screenshots from Xcode (swift) to Allure report?

I use this code in a body of my test case for make screenshoots:

```
XCTContext.runActivity(named: "TestRunActivity") { (activity) in
     let screen = XCUIScreen.main
     let fullscreenshot = screen.screenshot()
     let fullScreenshotAttachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: fullscreenshot)
     fullScreenshotAttachment.name = startWord + name
     fullScreenshotAttachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
     activity.add(fullScreenshotAttachment)
 }
```

I saw some examples how to implement this on Java but I need do it on swift.

Screenshoots are store at .xcresult dir but not attaches to Allure report. 
How can I get this result ?
Thanks

Comment: is Allure implemented for Swift? Could you share link to the pod (or carthage)?

Comment: I don't know also. I try use allure only for test reports. But also don't know how to describe test steps into allure report and other features of allure on swift. I cannot google for any example for Xcode plus allure. Are you have experience with allure or other test report systems maybe?

Comment: Looking at Allure documentation there is no implementation for swift

Comment: Only this 
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/blob/56fce7a55aa0c7f28eec0904908e900dfffdc462/plugins/xctest-plugin/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/xctest/ResultsUtils.java

can help us, as I understand

Comment: ah, yeah, sorry -- allure is indeed working with xcresults, I guess I was referring to outdated documentation

Comment: Solved: rebuild allure with new pull request from repo. Used java: 8.0.222.j9-adpt (via sdkman)